# Bootstrap-select live search regardless of word order

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select

I am using snapappointments bootstrap-select dropdowns with live search on.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="new york city" value="NY">New York City</option>
  ...
</select>
```

```
$('select').selectpicker();
```

Is it possible to override the standard way the live search works, so that I could type in keywords, regardless of their order?
In extent, in the above example NY should be found for all of the phrases below:

- new city
- city new
- new york city

In this particular example I know I could just include all permutations as "data-tokens", but it would not work so good in a select with a couple hundred options, each of 10-20 words.